# Passing double backslashes to a macro

Tags: macros

I'm trying to write a macro in which one of the arguments is a double backslash, to obtain a column matrix, but I'm unable to escape the `\` character.   Here's a simple example that throws an error.   It also throws an error if I try `\myBmatrix{z_1 \\ z_2}` or `\myBmatrix{z_1 \\\\\\ z_2}`

(The actual macro I'm trying to write is more complex but I thought I'd start with this silly one)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\def\myBmatrix#1{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    {{#1}}
    \end{bmatrix}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\myBmatrix{z_1 \\\\ z_2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the error? That is, what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want (some of your lines are commented and replaced by my versions):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\def\myBmatrix#1{
    \begin{bmatrix}
%    {{#1}}
    #1
    \end{bmatrix}
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
%\myBmatrix{z_1 \\\\ z_2}
\myBmatrix{z_1 \\ z_2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is changing to `\gdef` supposed to do?

Comment: @cfr You are right. This time it is unneeded. Corrected.

Comment: `\def` works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Przemysław Scherwentke.     Could you explain why the curly brackets create a problem?

Comment: @LeoSimon A cell inside arraay-like environments is a group. Hence, using curly braces, you may obtain an unbalanced group. This is only general sketch of the problem: I haven't analysed `matrix` environment yet.

Answer (score 4):

`\def` will work if you just remove the excess of curly brackets and additional backslashes. However, `\newcommand*` would be better since this is for LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcommand*\myBmatrix[1]{%
  \begin{bmatrix}
    #1
  \end{bmatrix}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \myBmatrix{z_1 \\ z_2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Remember that a backslash doesn't escape a backslash in TeX. If `\\` doesn't work, `\\\\` isn't likely to be better ;).

[image: output]